# CoAP authentication using DTLS

Tags: aes

what is the meaning of this notation ??

> AES{Yi, (Yi XOR Ki | nonce1)}

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhattacharyya-core-coap-lite-auth-00

Comment: Tried to explain, but without information on what precisely you don't get, it is impossible to create a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the encryption using the key $Y_i$ of the constructed message.

The message consists of key $K_i$ XOR'ed (bit for bit) with the previous key $Y_i$, followed by ${nonce}_1$.

> where $K_i$ is the
>      potential session key if the handshake is successful, '${nonce}_1$' is
>      pseudo randomly generated nonce specific to one authentication
>      session. Both $K_i$ and ${nonce}_1$ is 128 bit each. Total message size is
>      256 bit.

Comment: (including grammar mistake, I mean, "Both $K_i$ and ${nonce}_1$ **are** 128 bit each")

Comment: thanx.. so the total encrypting payload here is 256 bits with Yi XOR Ki and nonce1. the whole 256 bits are then encrypted in AES with Yi.

Comment: Yep, that's it.